# jQuery.load doesn't work in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This works in FF, but not in IE 7 and 8.  Is there anyway to make it work in IE?

```
setInterval(function() {
    $("#content").load(location.href+" #content>*","");
}, 5000);
```

(this code is from http://blog.mediasoft.be/partial-page-refresh-with-ajax-and-jquery/)

Comment: What is that weird ` #content>*` part for? That looks *wrong*.

Comment: @Pekka `.load()` takes a selector after the URL.

Comment: Plus, I don't understand the entire tutorial. What is the point of refreshing a DIV with *itself* every five seconds?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the last `""` is, but it can be left off, IE may have trouble with the empty data param:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $("#content").load(location.href+" #content>*");
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Actually that's for the oncomplete function.  I actually don't have it empty, I have a function specified, but still doesn't work in IE.

Comment: @Pravhu - if you want help here you need to post your actual code, if you're changing the code you may or may not be including the actual issue...or creating other ones making the answers to your questions invalid.

Comment: @Prabhu then you'll have to do some debugging. Is the function fired in the first place (use alert() to find out?) Does the Ajax request fire (Use IE8's developer tools to find out?)

Comment: Why is there a space between location.href and #content ?

Comment: @themerlinproject - by putting a space your using the `.load("<href> <selector>") overload, and it's loading the `id="content"` element from that url, instead of all the html it returns.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any javascript in the returned HTML? 
Is so, that could be causing the problem. Remove the javascript and put in the parent page in a callback function.